# Transpose and repeat column

Tags: google-sheets

I know this might be a long shot but here it goes:

Let's assume I have this data:

```
  A     B
2014    1
2015    2
2016    3
2017    4
2018
```

Those columns are not related. But based on that I would like to create a table like this:

```
2014 2014 2014 2014 2015 2015 2015 2015 2016 2016 2016 2016
  1    2    3   4    1     2    3    4    1    2    3    4
```

Or even better have each column repeated 5 times. What I want to achieve i that I will have data for each year and quarter, and then I would like to display each quarter separately and at the end of each year to have an average:

```
2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2016 2016 2016 2016 2016
  1    2    3   4    avg   1    2    3    4   avg   1    2    3    4   avg
```

I've used `TRANSPOSE(A2:B6)` but I'm stuck on the repetition side of things, if it's even possible

Since I have data in a first column, perhaps something like this is easier to achieve:

```
A           B      C     D
                 2014  2015
Label A     1      x     x
Label A     2      x     x
Label A     3
Label A     4
Label B     1
```

The labels in A column are taken using QUERY, just a list of, for example, people - can I repeat them? The Xs would then be a singular query to get right data for column A,B, and C

Answer (score 0):

There is `rept` for repeating a string a given number of times. It can be abused for other data by way of `join` and `split`, if you can pick a suitable delimiter (some character that isn't going to be present in the data). I use | as a delimiter:

```
=split(join("", arrayformula(rept(A2:A6 & "|", 5))), "|")
```

This puts the content of A2:A6 in a row, repeating each entry 5 times.

Similar trick to have the content of B2:B6 repeated but in a loop: 1, 2, 3, 4, avg, 1, 2, 3, 4, avg ... :

```
=split(rept(join("|", B2:B6), 7), "|")
```

Here 7 is the number of times the loop should be repeated.